# I cant find "disable permission monitring" feature in samsung a31

Tags: android, testing, appium, samsung-mobile, usb-debugging

I want to do testing on my android. i am new to tesing, i have enable developer option but when i tired to connect appium server with my device it give error, failed, even though my device is connected. (checked through adb devices). but after running the code my device automatically goes offline

my installation is right because it work on oppo phone(i have tested it). the only difference is i turn on disable permission monitering option on oppo and i cant this feature on my samsung a31, please help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.